# Passing user Input from a HTML page to a Perl script and displaying the results in webpage

Tags: html, mysql, apache, perl, cgi

I have the existing setup as below.

## Existing Setup:

Below is the user interactive perl script which takes the EmpNo as argument and prints the Name and Salary of the employee from the  Employee table.
Currently I am running this script in terminal and output is also shown on the terminal.

## Perl Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;

my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "dbname";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid = "uid";

print "Enter employee Number \n";

my $input1 =<>;


my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Empname ,Salary FROM Employee WHERE EmpNo ='$input1' ");

$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
print "Number of rows found :" + $sth->rows;
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
   my ($name, $salary) = @row;
   print "Name = $name, Salary = $salary \n";
}
$sth->finish()
```

## Output: perl test.pl

Enter employee Number
207711
Name=John Salary=10000

## Requirement:

Instead on running the script on terminal with user Input . I like to have a HTML web page where user can select the EmpNo from the drop down list and this EmpNo should be passed to the Perl script  on clicking the submit
button. The script then should fetch the database details and show on webpage.

## Brief Idea:

Something like this with forms.

```
<FORM action="/test.pl" method="POST">

< select name = "Employee details" >
    <option selected = "selected">EmpNo</option>
    <option value = "207711">207711</option>
    <option value = "207712">207712</option>
    <option value = "207713">207713</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</FORM>
```

I am open to use CGI and have Apache installed. Awaiting your valuable response. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: If by "CGI" you mean CGI.pm, that's not really a great option nowadays (its use is actually [discouraged in the official documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE)). See [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) instead.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You must set up an HTML page, and your HTTP server must be configured to expect a URL of `/test.pl`. Then you must alter your Perl script to accept input data through the CGI interface and deliver HTML output instead of simple text. All of that cannot be handled in a single answer

Comment: @Borodin : HTML page is ready and URL of the /test.pl too. Could you please suggest  the changes required to accept input data through CGI interface. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just winging this, without trying it, but just add/change these lines in your code:

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
print header;
print qq(<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\n);
print qq(<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">\n);
print "<head>\n";
print "  <title>Page Title Goes Here!</title>\n";
print "</head>\n";

my $input1 = param('Employee details') || "";
```

I hadn't heard about CGI.pm not being recommended, but the basic idea from above should still work.

Comment: Hi @jimtut, Thanks. It works. Now Iam able to read data from HTML page into Perl/Cgi and work on it. Currently I am copying the result from Sql query to a text file. How to print the text file(as a text or html?) in the same cgi?

Comment: There are easy ways to read in a text file (Google for "Perl file slurp"), but I'm not sure that's really what you want.  Do you mean that the Perl code is storing the SQL query results in a text file & then you want to display it on the webpage?  Why not just use code like in your example which is justing `print`ing the results?  Those `print` commands will print right to the webpage.  If for some reason you do need to read the SQL query results from a text file, you can easily "slurp" it in.  But, try to consolidate all of the code (SQL query & printing to webpage) into a single Perl script.

Comment: Ran out of room in the last comment.  I'm sure others will hate this idea, but for ease of maintenance, I put the HTML input form into the Perl CGI too.  This requires a little more code, to detect whether this is the initial run of the script or if it's the form submission, but then you have all the code related to input, searching, and output in one file.  Again, many people will say that that's a horrible way to structure code, but it makes maintenance of reasonably-small scripts very easy when everything is all together like that.

Comment: Displaying the sql output directly  in web page has some indentation problem . So, I redirected it to text file and then made hyperlink to the text file so that users can click and check the result. Many thanks!!. Will try to look into your second option of including html also in cgi

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please accept this as the correct answer, if you're all set.